# Adding http:// to URL still gets interpreted as incomplete URL

Tags: ruby

I wrote a script that grabs the headers of any http or https website, and I wanted to add a feature that adds the protocol to the beginning of the URL if I don't specify myself. For some reason it still reads the finished URL as an invalid one and throws an error.

```
def headers(hosts)
uri = URI.parse(hosts)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

if !uri.scheme
    uri = "http://#{uri}"
    puts uri

elsif uri.scheme == 'https'
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
else
    false
end


begin
    Timeout::timeout(8) do
        http.start do
            resp = http.head('/')

            puts "#{resp.code} #{resp.message}"
            resp.each { |k, v| puts "#{k.capitalize}: #{v}" }
            puts "\n"

            http.finish
        end
    end

rescue SocketError
    puts "\nInvalid hostname: #{uri}"

rescue Timeout::Error
    puts "\n#{uri} doesn't seem to exist. Did you type the URL correctly?"

rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
    puts "\nERROR: #{uri}; Connection refused!"
end

end


begin
headers(ARGV[0])

rescue Interrupt
puts "\n"
end
```

You should be able to see that early on in the script, under; if !uri.scheme, I added puts uri. I wanted to be sure that I was creating the URL properly so I added that to test. Now, say for example I run the script and try to grab headers from google.com. The script adds http:// in front of it, and sure enough it puts: http://google.com. Yet it doesn't interpret it correctly somehow. Trying http://google.com works, but trying google.com and adding http:// on doesn't. I want to understand why. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors: one, you are not reparsing the url string into an object. Two, you are not creating a new HTTP object if you added the schema. Try something like this:

```
if !uri.scheme
  uri = URI.parse "http://#{uri}"
end

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
if uri.scheme == 'https'
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## The problem

Because `uri` doesn't contain a string, it contains a `URI::HTTP` object:

```ruby
uri = URI.parse("http://www.ruby-lang.org/")
p uri
# => #<URI::HTTP:0x202281be URL:http://www.ruby-lang.org/>
```

You are using this in your `http` variable when you initialize `Net::HTTP`. You simply have to create a new `Net::HTTP` object with the new URI.

## An alternative

I noticed that's a lot of code for a simple task. Here's an alternative using `rest-client`:

```
RestClient.get("http://www.google.com/").headers
```

This also works with `https` or without a scheme.